# Linking to open scene graph statically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static, static-linking, openscenegraph

Is there a way to link to the open scene graph libraries statically?

I compiled osg on windows 7, and it has both static and dlls, but I want to link statically so I don't have to rely on the dlls. The point is so that I can just carry the exe file for distribution and have other people test it without having to worry about the dlls being missing. I don't know what I have to change in the settings for it to link only to the static libraries.

I'm using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

See the CMake option

DYNAMIC_OPENSCENEGRAPH
Set to ON to build OpenSceneGraph for dynamic linking.  Use OFF for static.